# How to Change Resolution in Virtual Box for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VM Virtual Box but when I'm shifting to full screen I'm not getting full screen resolution ! is there any way that we don't feel any difference between real installed ubuntu and VM ubuntu !

Comment: You did not specify what is your host - if it is Windows 7 on a laptop you might be experiencing the same issue my friend had with her laptop. If your system also has a dedicated video card add vbox to the list using it, instead of the integrated one. When seamless mode is working, but screen aspect ratio is ignored by the guest this could be the answer (on Windows host).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the VirtualBox guest add-ins/additions in Ubuntu for it to work with the VirtualBox host system and give you more screen resolutions.

In your VM open a Terminal:

```
> sudo apt-get install dkms
> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

Comment: When trying this, I got an error "virtualbox-guest-additions has no installation candidate".

Changing "virtualbox-guest-additions" to "virtualbox-guest-additions-iso" fixed this